# How to get container instance in sonata Admin class (v 4.0.0-rc.1)?

Tags: symfony, admin, sonata

```
$this->getConfigurationPool()->getContainer();
```

The getContainer method doesn't seem to exist in version 4.0.0-rc.1

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this with dependency injection.

For example, I've injected ParameterBagInterface to get application params in my sonata admin.

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ParameterBag\ParameterBagInterface;

class ProtocolAdmin extends AbstractAdmin
{
    private $params;

    public function __construct(string $code, string $class, string $baseControllerName, ParameterBagInterface $params)
    {
        parent::__construct($code, $class, $baseControllerName);
        $this->params = $params;
    }
  
    ...
}
```